# Lebesgue measure/integral problem - where do I go wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification

> Let $f\geq0$ be a bounded function supported in a measurable set $E$ with $m(E)<\infty$. Show that if $\int_E f=0$, then $m(E)=0$.

**My proof:** Let $E_\epsilon=\{x\in E:f(x)\geq\epsilon\}$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, 
$$
0=\int_Ef\geq\int_{E_\epsilon}f\geq\int_{E_\epsilon}\epsilon=\epsilon m(E_\epsilon)\geq 0.
$$
Since $\epsilon>0$, we must have $m(E_\epsilon)=0$. Finally, $E=\cup_{k\geq1}E_{1/k}$, so $m(E)\leq\sum_{k\geq 1}m(E_{1/k})=0$.

**Silly counterexample:** Take $f\equiv 0$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Then $\int_{[0,1]} f=0$ but $m([0,1])=1$.

Clearly I am missing some sort of minor detail here, but I cannot figure it out. What am I doing wrong in my proof? It seems like this problem is not true as stated (because of my counterexample), so I want to know why my proof is wrong.

EDIT: Is it because $E\not=\cup_{k\geq 1}E_{1/k}$? For example, if $f(x)=0$, then $x\not\in E_\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0?$ I suppose this proof becomes true if $f>0$ for all $x\in E$, for then there will always exist some $\epsilon>0$ for which $x\in E_\epsilon$.

Comment: I think so, and I may have found out what is actually wrong with my proof.

Comment: I think "Supported in a measurable set $E$" means that the function has support in $E$. Or maybe it means $E=supp(f)$.  Either way, seems like $f$ has non-zero values, since $supp(f)=\{ x : f(x) \neq 0 \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that we need not have $E=\bigcup_{k\geq 1} E_{1/k}.$ Instead, we have
$$\{x\in E: f(x)>0\} = \bigcup_{k\geq 1} E_{1/k}.$$
Note the strict inequality in the LHS rather than $\geq.$ Hence, the problem is true if we assume $f>0$ on $E$, rather than $f\geq 0$.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Thanks for clarifying.